Flutter (android only): Google Sign In Error in after uploading to play console: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, s8.b: 10: , null, null)
I'm using google_sign_in: ^6.2.1 package to add Sign in with Google functionality to the Flutter App. But this throws PlatformException(sign_in_failed, s8.b: 10: , null, null) error after releasing the app to Google Play Console (caught by Sentry). Since after signing in with Google I also want the idToken value, I'm using web client id. I have therefore created 3 OAuth client ids in cloud console:

The web client id (which I pass as serverClientId in GoogleSignIn)
Android client id with debug keystore SHA-1 value.
Android client id with release keystore SHA-1 value.

The app runs perfectly in debug (flutter run) and release (flutter run --release) mode. But, in the version I download from play store (internal testing), the signin fails.
Code:
final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(serverClientId: googleClientId);

Future<String?> _getIdTokenWithGoogle() async {
  await _googleSignIn.signOut();
  final account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final idToken = (await account?.authentication)?.idToken;
  return idToken;
}

I've already tried the following:

Added 3 SHA-1 values to firebase console (release keystore, debug keystore and upload (the one from play console))
Have updated google-services.json file.
Added the support email to firebase console.


if you have an android app why would you want to use a web client?  Web clients are for web applications.    I think a better question would be why you are not getting an id token back from android signin.
